# You will meet someone, and he will throw your father in a deep fryer

Tags: lateral-thinking, language

You are going to meet someone special. You'll love him, I swear. But there are some things you need to know about him first.

- If he says you're going to be liberated, bring a jacket.
- He always has a dumb smile on his face when you talk to him about leaving.
- You'll have to forgive him if he thinks someone might get pregnant from being asked the wrong question.

Let's see if you're ready to meet him. One shocking thing he might try to do is suggest to throw your father in a deep fryer. But as strange as it sounds, he really doesn't mean anything bad by it.

Do you understand what he might be trying to accomplish by it?

---

Already solved, but if you still want to have a go and need hints:

> * He has a mascot that he loves so much he takes it on daily walks.

Another:

> Me: my papa? in the fryer??

> Him: fine, we'll get others then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He is trying to

> learn Spanish.

*If he says you're going to be liberated, bring a jacket.*

> *frio* sounds like *free* but means *cold*.

*He always has a dumb smile on his face when you talk to him about leaving.*

> Not sure. Maybe you leave at *sunrise*, which sounds like *sonrisa*, meaning *smile*.

*You'll have to forgive him if he thinks someone might get pregnant from being asked the wrong question.*

> *pregunta*/*preguntar* sounds like *pregnant* but means *question*/*to question*. Or *embarazado* means *pregnant* and you might be *embarrassed* from being asked the wrong question.

One shocking thing he might try to do is suggest to throw your father in a deep fryer.

> *papas fritas* means *french fries* (literally fried potatoes). *papá* means *father*.

Comment: Nice! I was thinking about something else for the smile and the pregnant things, though

Comment: @Dotan was it about irse/reirse? (leaving/laughing?)

Comment: Leave - go for the exit